# Find the minimal lexographical string formed by merging two strings

Tags: string, algorithm

Suppose we are given two strings s1 and s2(both lowercase). We have two find the minimal lexographic string that can be formed by merging two strings.

At the beginning , it looks prettty simple as merge of the mergesort algorithm. But let us see what can go wrong.

s1: zyy

s2: zy

Now if we perform merge on these two we must decide which z to pick as they are equal, clearly if we pick z of s2 first then the string formed will be:

zyzyy

If we pick z of s1 first, the string formed will be:

zyyzy which is correct.

As we can see the merge of mergesort can lead to wrong answer.

Here's another example:

s1:zyy

s2:zyb

Now the correct answer will be zybzyy which will be got only if pick z of s2 first.

There are plenty of other cases in which the simple merge will fail. My question is Is there any standard algorithm out there used to perform merge for such output.

Comment: how do you exactly you merge the two strings? Each step you pop a character from the beginning of one of them?

Comment: @svs start from left of both strings and pick the smaller character.

Comment: The problem is thinking that it's simply the merge operation of merge sort. Merge sort works on the assumption that your sublists are already sorted. Your string's are not sorted, hence the problem.

Comment: @dhke We cannot change the two input strings, hence we cannot sort them.

Comment: @SumeetSingh Yeah, but that leaves defining the "merge" operating up to you, as you violate the precondition (sublists are sorted) for the mergesort merge. In your case the solution is probably: If both candidates are equal, pull both. But again: You need to define what you want as a result.

Comment: @dhke Resutl should be minimal lexographic string.

Comment: @SumeetSingh And what exactly is that? What operations are allowed for the "merge"? As is, I consider this underspecified, because I need to know how to merge the strings to determine what the lexicographically minimum possible result would be. But exactly the merge operation is open for discussion from the question.

Comment: @dhke It means the one that comes at least  position in a dictionary. The only operation that is allowed is u have to pick one char at a time from the left of string, of course main problem comes when both chars are equal which i showed.

Comment: @SumeetSingh Shouldn't the expected result then be `zzyyy` (or `zzyyby`, respectively), because you are otherwise violating the merge rule? Or returning back to my initial comment: What rules are to apply?

Comment: @Sumeet, if you are doing it char by char how is your 2nd example zybzyy correct?

Answer (score 2):

You could use dynamic programming. In `f[x][y]` store the  minimal lexicographical string such that you've taken `x` charecters from the first string `s1` and `y` characters from the second `s2`. You can calculate `f` in bottom-top manner using the update:

```
f[x][y] = min(f[x-1][y] + s1[x], f[x][y-1] + s2[y]) \\ the '+' here represents
                                                    \\ the concatenation of a 
                                                    \\ string and a character
```

You start with `f[0][0] = "" (empty string)`.

For efficiency you can store the strings in `f` as references. That is, you can store in `f` the objects

```
class StringRef {
    StringRef prev;
    char c;
}
```

To extract what string you have at certain `f[x][y]` you just follow the references. To udapate you point back to either `f[x-1][y]` or `f[x][y-1]` depending on what your update step says.

Comment: Appreciate the answer but length of s1 and s2 can go up 10^5, Hence We require a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the solution can be almost the same as you described (the "mergesort"-like approach), except that with special handling of equality. So long as the first characters of both strings are equal, you look ahead at the second character, 3rd, etc. If the end is reached for some string, consider the first character of the other string as the next character in the string for which the end is reached, etc. for the 2nd character, etc. If the ends for both strings are reached, then it doesn't matter from which string to take the first character. Note that this algorithm is `O(N)` because after a look-ahead on equal prefixes you know the whole look-ahead sequence (i.e. string prefix) to include, not just one first character.

EDIT: you look ahead so long as the current i-th characters from both strings are equal and alphabetically not larger than the first character in the current prefix.

Comment: Why downvoting? Any counter-example?